# Access - Fields

Tags: ms-access

I have two fields in my table if both of these fields values are "0" I don't want the record to show in my form but if it happens to be any other combination I do want it to show.

I'm figuring it needs to be some sort of If statement but I'm not sure how to get this to reflect in my form.

Im assuming it will need to look something like:

```
    Private Sub TypeList_AfterUpdate()
    If (OutboundReservations.Value And InboundReservations.Value = "0") Then Me.showrecord = False
    Else
    Me.showrecord = True
    End Sub
    End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I've added my answer, but have noticed an error in you VBA code: ` If (OutboundReservations.Value And InboundReservations.Value = "0") `.  You need to state what you want both values to be.  At the moment this is saying `IF OutboundReservations.Value = TRUE AND  InboundReservations.Value = "0"`.  This should be `IF OutboundReservations.Value = '0' AND  InboundReservations.Value = '0'`   The `"0"` is also being read as text - just use `0` if it's stored as a number.  `Me.ShowRecord = False` should be on a new line - it will read the `IF` statement as one line and error on the `ELSE` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a query based on your table that removes those records and use the query as the data source for your form.
Something like: `SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM MyTable WHERE Field2 <> 0 AND Field3 <> 0`

Or, as an alternative you could add the condition to the `Filter` property on the form: `Field2 <> 0 AND Field3 <> 0` and set the `Filter On Load` property to `Yes`

Comment: Thanks for this I had tried the query option but I cant work out how to get it to show the records correctly - If my outbound is 1 and my inbound is 0 as I have stated in my query <> 0 it also removes this record.... I don't quite get why though when Ive put it in as WHERE OutboundReservation <>'0" AND InboundReservation <> "0"

Comment: Could you post the SQL for the query please?  (Use View ~ SQL View)

Comment: SELECT Numbers.OutboundReservations, Numbers.InboundReservations
FROM Numbers
WHERE (((Numbers.OutboundReservations)<>"0") AND ((Numbers.InboundReservations)<>"0"));